# Dependently typed trees in C++ compile-time

Tags: c++, tree, dependent-type

I am trying to come up with some dependently-typed data structures for C++, at compile-time. I somewhat tackled the primary example, a list type with its length encoded in type, aka. `list<T, length>`. There are simple invariants to be easily preserved here like you can be sure that appending two lists will have the sum of length's of its part as length etc. Trivial so far. I am now moving onto dependently typed trees, aka. `binary_tree<T, height>`, so that I can modify this to achieve height-balanced trees. Idea is to discard any operation that would break the height-balanced at compile-time. This whole thing is also a nice exercise in recursive thinking for me.

I am going to present my attempt and will ask about the error later.

```
// A binary tree of height N
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct binary_tree
{
    constexpr binary_tree(const T &node, binary_tree<T, N-1> left,
                                         binary_tree<T, N-1> right)
    :root{node}, left{left}, right{right}, size{left.size + right.size + 1}
    {}

    const T root;
    const binary_tree<T, N-1> left;
    const binary_tree<T, N-1> right;
    const std::size_t size; // num of elements in tree
    constexpr static const std::size_t capacity = 2^N -1;
};

template <typename T>
struct binary_tree<T, 0>
{
    const std::size_t size{0};
    constexpr static const bool nil = true;
};

template <typename T>
using empty_tree = binary_tree<T,0>;


template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto insert(const T& elem, const binary_tree<T, N> &tree) {
    if constexpr (N == 0)
        return binary_tree<T, 1>{elem, empty_tree<T>{}, empty_tree<T>{}};
    else if (elem <= tree.root && tree.size < binary_tree<T, N>::capacity)
        return binary_tree<T, N>{tree.root, 
                                 insert(elem, tree.left),
                                 tree.right};
    else if (elem <= tree.root && tree.size == binary_tree<T, N>::capacity)
        return binary_tree<T, N + 1>{tree.root, 
                                 insert(elem, tree.left),
                                 tree.right};
    else if (elem > tree.root && tree.size < binary_tree<T, N>::capacity)
        return binary_tree<T, N>{tree.root, 
                                 tree.left,
                                 insert(elem, tree.right)};
    else if (elem > tree.root && tree.size == binary_tree<T, N>::capacity)
        return binary_tree<T, N + 1>{tree.root, 
                                    tree.left,
                                    insert(elem, tree.right)};
}

int main() {
    constexpr binary_tree<int, 1> tr1{2, empty_tree<int>{}, empty_tree<int> {}};
    constexpr auto tr2 = insert(1, tr1);
}
```

The thing is, my `insert` function is trying to instantiate the calls to other branches as well, since only the first one is a `constexpr if`. Somehow, I need to make all cases an `else if constexpr` but this seems not possible since comparing `elem` to see which subtree to insert is not `constexpr`. Why is `elem < tree.root` is not `constexpr`, after all, they are two constant values.

Edit: I realized it is problematic to take left and right subtrees to be of same height, not necessarily true for general trees. This confuses me more.

Comment: Oh, I had the mistake of assuming left and right subtrees will have the same height, you can consider that when answering.